# Using assertion library outside of testing for list manipulations

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In my current project I do a lot of list manipulations on front end, and I realised that using something like chai or other assertion library could save me a lot of time and make code quite readable.

Though while Chaijs is cool and all, it's api is not exactly functional and currying friendly. My questions are:

Is it actually a good idea to look for assertion library to use outside of testing environment for array manipulations/filtering. Or am I smoking crack?

And if yes, any one have success story with any library?

Some of simplified examples of what I'm trying to do:

```
const people = [
  {name: "David Smith", age: 25, livedIn: ["London", "Paris"]},
  {name: "John Smith", age: 30, livedIn: ["New York"]},
  {name: "John Gates", age 25, livedIn: ["London", "New York"]}
]
```

Currently we are using plain closures, and when checks are easy enough, it's all good and shiny:

```
people
  // Let's find 25 year olds
  .filter((person) => person.age === 25);
  // And see who is among them john
  .filter((person) => person.name.indexOf("John") === 0);
```

Now that's all plain and easy, but then we need to start testing deep properties: `person.names.firstName`, or `person.cities[<index>].postCode` and this is what assertion library does great on paper, chai or jasmine have methods to do just that, example from chaijs documentation:

```
expect(tea).to.have.property('flavors').with.length(3);
```

For example with assertion library I can find people who lived in London:

```
people
  .filter((person) => {
    return expect(person.livedIn).to.includes("London");
  });
```

Or *not* lived in London:

```
people
  .filter((person) => {
    return expect(person.livedIn).not.to.includes("London");
  });
```

And of course ranges:

```
expect({price: 50}).to.be.within(40, 60);
```

Now while both chaijs and jasmine do functinally what I need, their API is not functional, I would love to have api close to [Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda) or i.e. Composable functions, with rules first, and iteratee last. Something along the lines of:

```
people
   .filter(within('age', 20, 40)) // Filter age property, to be 20 < age < 40
   .filter(contains('livedIn', 'London', 'Boston')) // Further filter people, by place they lived in.
```

Of course I don't want or need exactly that API. It can differ in any way as long as I can curry it.

Comment: Could you give an example (with code) as to how you would use the assertion library to help you with list manipulation?

Comment: Sure @GreenGiant ping me if you want more examples!

Comment: I don't have experience doing this sort of thing with an existing libraries, but sounds like you already know a few. One option would be to create your own API, possibly by forking and modifying one of the libraries you've mentioned here.

Comment: Yeah, wiriting yet another library in JavaScript is what I'm trying to avoid :) I'm not against it, but I want to be sure that I do my due diligence before spending more of my clients money :)

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely not include an assertion library in your live code for this purpose. Libraries like Lodash have some useful functions you can use:

```
people
   .filter(p => _.inRange(p.age, 20, 40))
   .filter(p => _.intersection(['London', 'Boston'], p.livedIn).length > 0)
```

This may not be exactly the syntax you want. The nice thing with functional programming, though, is that it's pretty easy to write a few of your own functions to produce the filters you're looking for.

```
filters = {
    within: (property, low, high) => {
        return (obj) => {
            return obj[property] >= low && obj[property] <= high;
        };
    },
    ...
};

people
   .filter(filters.within('age', 20, 40)) // Filter age property, to be 20 < age < 40
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's exactly why I want to use assertion library, because I don't want to write new functions all the time :) Examples I gave are just a few among hundreds. Finance team will always want some new filtering or mapping by some criteria. We are doing similar to you suggestion right now, and it's quite boring and not scalable.

Comment: @DavidSergey: It's not really clear to me what you find lacking about libraries like Lodash and Ramda? They aren't assertion libraries, and they provide a lot of the type of functionality you're looking for. You say you'd like an API like Ramda, but you don't really explain why Ramda won't work for you. They don't have an `inRange()`-style function built in, but it'd be super easy to combine `lte()` and `gte()` to produce the same result.